# Granting php sudo acsess

Tags: php, fedora, sudo

I am trying to grant php sudo access (for automated share mounting). I was sucess full at granting php sudo access on one of my systems by adding daemond to the list of sudo's via

```
su --login -c 'visudo'
```

so now it contains the daemond like:

```
daemon  ALL=(ALL)  NOPASSWD: ALL
```

but when I try to run a simple php script:

```
<?php
echo "\nfirst: ";
echo shell_exec("whoami");
echo "\nsecond: ";
echo shell_exec("sudo ls");
?>
```

I get the results:

```
first: daemon
second:
```

That is any time I us shell_exec with sudo in the command nothing is returned or excited. How can I grant php sudo access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your web server error log... I bet you are getting an error like:

```
# tail -1 /var/log/httpd/error_log
sudo: sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo
```

If this is the case, try modifying your sudoers file and change/remove the requiretty line:

```
# grep requiretty /etc/sudoers
Defaults    requiretty
```

On the other hand, if you are simply trying to automatically mount and share something, autofs/automount might be worth investigating.

Comment: +1 for the autofs recommendation. Great stuff, and very under-utilized IMO.